# Superset db upgrade, throws "You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module "

Tags: flask, apache-superset

Hello I recently started to explore superset and visualization,

I'm following
[Superset offical link](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch#python-virtual-environment) and I'm able to install superset in Python Virtual Environment, but on Initialize the database

```
superset db upgrade
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Usage: superset [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'superset --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

Does anybody know where I'm missing to Initialize FLASK_APP environment variable in superset database initialization.

Machine used: Ubuntu 20, with : Python 3.9.16, Flask 2.1.3, Werkzeug 2.2.3

Comment: FYI there is no "Ubuntu 20". Presumably you mean Ubuntu 20.04 or Ubuntu 20.10; the latter of which is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

the manual is a bit unclear.

before i could do superset db upgrade I had to do

```
export FLASK_APP=superset
```

and then setup a config file [configuring superset](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset)

I noticed that at this stage you've only build the backend. And for the frontend, the manual refers to superset-frontend i think you have to download this from github.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do if there is new version.

I might try the docker version :).